# how to create simple nodejs script to wrap an binary/executable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, binary, wrapper

I want to create a nodejs file, that simple runs/wraps an executable binary file with all inputs and outputs.
For now at least on windows.

Why: 
wanted to install an executable tool over `npm install -g`, to have it in console, without `PATH` changes. (npm global packages are included in PATH)

Answer (score 0):

i used such solution:

```
const path = require("path");
const spawnSync = require('child_process').spawnSync;

const pathToMyExe = path.join(__dirname, 'bin', 'myfile.exe'); //just path to exe
const input = process.argv.slice(2); //minus "node" and "this js" arguments

spawnSync(pathToMyExe, input, {stdio: 'inherit'});
```

but for ".exe to PATH" problem, there is a simplier way (if you want windows only).
just set `bin` property in `package.json` to `pathToExe`.
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`bin-wrapper`](https://github.com/kevva/bin-wrapper) npm package.

***EDIT:***

There's a better alternative called [`bin-manager`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bin-manager).

## Installation:

```
$ npm install --save bin-manager
```

## Usage

```
const bmanager = require('bin-manager');

const base = 'https://github.com/imagemin/gifsicle-bin/raw/master/vendor';
const bin = bmanager('bin', 'gifsicle')
  .src(base + '/macos/gifsicle', 'darwin')
  .src(base + '/linux/x64/gifsicle', 'linux', 'x64')
  .src(base + '/win/x64/gifsicle.exe', 'win32', 'x64')
  .use(process.platform === 'win32' ? 'gifsicle.exe' : 'gifsicle');

bin.run(['--version'], (err, out) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(out.stdout);
});
```

Comment: I've created an enhanced version of the bin-wrapper module. It's called [bin-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bin-manager).

Comment: bin-manager is not a better alternative, it's your own written alternative, not updated for over a year.